# import modules from flirpy

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have recently changed from windows to mac and after my installation of Jupyter through brew, I have installed this python library called 'Flirpy' but when I am importing the module, it throws me this error.

Flirpy library link: https://github.com/LJMUAstroecology/flirpy#egg=flirpy

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fff'`

Any help will be greatly appreciated thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

FLIR Tools for Mac has been discontinued and removed from the Apple store.

[https://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1669/~/flir-tools-for-mac/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNjM2MTg3MjQzL2dlbi8xNjM2MTg3MjQzL3NpZC9mVVpldWkzV2R0cDZhTW44c1VQZ1RTb28lN0VaazElN0VvV3JCakw1NjRfMzk0JTdFV2p2bG5DNEFpS0Zka2NzbXhqY1F5azZkS0xyUUdVSDFVRmJTcTRwWWVQajkyX3Q1bFc0RFdmeEk0NmJmcVdOZldhdGNUNlVOU1FxNWclMjElMjE=](https://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1669/%7E/flir-tools-for-mac/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNjM2MTg3MjQzL2dlbi8xNjM2MTg3MjQzL3NpZC9mVVpldWkzV2R0cDZhTW44c1VQZ1RTb28lN0VaazElN0VvV3JCakw1NjRfMzk0JTdFV2p2bG5DNEFpS0Zka2NzbXhqY1F5azZkS0xyUUdVSDFVRmJTcTRwWWVQajkyX3Q1bFc0RFdmeEk0NmJmcVdOZldhdGNUNlVOU1FxNWclMjElMjE=)